# useState set call not reflecting change immediately prior to first render of app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

New to React Hooks and unsure how to solve. I have the following snippet of code within my App.js file below.

What I am basically trying to achieve is to get the user logged in by calling the `getUser()` function and once I have the user id, then check if they are an authorised user by calling the function `checkUserAccess()` for user id.

Based on results within the the `validIds` array, I check to see if it's  true or false and set authorised state to true or false via the `setAuthorised()` call.

My problem is, I need this to process first prior to performing my first render within my App.js file.

At the moment, it's saying that I'm not authroised even though I am.

Can anyone pls assist with what I am doing wrong as I need to ensure that `authorised` useState is set correctly prior to first component render of application, i.e. path="/"

```
const [theId, setTheId] = useState('');
const [authorised, setAuthorised] = useState(false);


  const checkUserAccess = async (empid) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/get-valid-users");
      const allUsers = await response.json();

      const validIds = allUsers.map(({ id }) => id);
      const isAuthorised = validIds.includes(empid);

      if (isAuthorised) {
        setAuthorised(true)
      } else {
        setAuthorised(false)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  }  
    
    const getUser = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/get-user");
          const theId= await response.json();
          
          setTheId(theId);
          checkUserAccess(theId);
    
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        }
      }
    
     useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
      }, []);
```

Comment: I'd add another `useEffect` triggered by `theId` value, and that should call the `checkUserAccess` function

Comment: Personally I would use 1 useSstate & 1 useEffect,..  Otherwise you get multiple renders for no reason.

Comment: @MarioVernari - could you please provide an example of your solution by possibly using my snippet of code.

Comment: What is the condition your app starting rendering and checking if user is authorized or not?

Comment: @Keith - again, could you also  please provide an example of your solution by possibly using my snippet of code.

Comment: @NikitaMazur It's not so much the condition but I am basically passing my `authorised` value as a prop to my Home component and in there it checks if authorised. If not, it performs a `<Redirect to="/access-not-allowed" />`

Comment: But user is not authorized by default) so it redirects on first render)

Comment: @NikitaMazur - I did say that I was new to React Hooks. Will your solution still work for my requirement?

Comment: You must render your app only if theId in the state is present, which will mean your user is fetched

Comment: If you look at the example I posted, I do -> `if (!user) return <div>Loading</div>;` This should stop the redirect, as it will wait until the setUser is called before deciding to redirect or not.

Comment: Yeah, basically me and @Keith done the same thing)

Comment: I basically don't want to render anything until I know the user is a valid user or not. If valid then the `<Home />` component will be rendered accordingly otherwise the user will be redirected to a `<AccessNotAllowed />` component.

Comment: Yes, sure, the user and auth flag are set at the same time) Updated my answer with @Keith code for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are wanting to partially render when you get the user ID, and then get the access level.  There is no reason to have multiple useState's / useEffect's.

Just get your user and then get your access level and use that.

Below is an example.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

const checkUserAccess = async (empid) => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/get-valid-users");
  const allUsers = await response.json();
  const validIds = allUsers.map(({ id }) => id);
  const isAuthorised = validIds.includes(empid);
  return isAuthorised;
}  
    
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/get-user");
    const theId= await response.json();
    const access = await checkUserAccess(theId);
    setUser({
      theId,
      access
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
}
    
useEffect(() => {
  getUser();
}, []);  

if (!user) return <div>Loading</div>;

return <>{user.theId}</>
```

Answer (score 1):

This way it should work
but keep in mind that you must render your app only if theId in the state is present, which will mean your user is properly fetched.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({ theId: '', isAutorized: false })    
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const idResp = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/get-user");
    const theId = await idResp.json();
    const authResp = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/get-valid-users");
    const allUsers = await authResp.response.json();

    const validIds = allUsers.map(({ id }) => id);
    const isAuthorised = validIds.includes(theId);
    setState({ theId, isAuthorised })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
   getUser();
}, []);

if (!state.theId) return <div>Loading</div>;

if (state.theId && !isAuthorized) return <AccessNotAllowed />

return <Home />
```